# Given an operator that is a Fourier multiplier. What are the conditions on the operator for which one may transform in and out to apply it correctly.

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Let's say I have an operator $\hat{A}$ that acts as a Fourier multiplier with some function f(k) such that application of this operator on a function g(k) in Fourier space is f(k)*g(k). An example would be the second derivative where f(k) would be $-k^2$ and application to g(k) becomes $-k^{2}*g(k)$.

My question is that if I have this operator are there any conditions on the nature of the Fourier multiplier f(k) that make it impossible for me to apply it numerically using the following method.

1. I take a function I want to apply my operator to $\psi(x)$ and Fourier transform it to bring it to Fourier space. This turns it into $\phi(k)$.
2. I then apply my Fourier multiplier.
3. I then apply the inverse Fourier transform to bring it back to my initial position space.

My first thoughts were that a Fourier multiplier that is discontinuous or unbounded would cause great problems. But I am honestly unsure of how to even start trying to prove if a certain Fourier multiplier would not cause any problems. I was thinking that using the Nyquist theorem would be important in formulating a solution to this but I am unsure. The Fourier multiplier I am most interested in is $|k|^\alpha$ where $\alpha \in (1,2)$. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your Fourier multiplier is essentially a differentiation operator, if you’re trying to do numerics it’s probably more worthwhile to find a robust method of computing fractional derivatives. Differentiation is an unbounded operator, so small errors can become large if you’re not careful, and these errors seem somewhat difficult to control if you’re numerically computing a Fourier transform and its inverse.